# Why can't I deploy from my local repository to a remote Maven repository?

Tags: maven, deployment, repository

I'm using Maven 3.0.4 and want to deploy something in my local repository to a remote repository, to which I've verified I have access.  I'm using the below command …

```
mvn -X deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.directwebremoting -DartifactId=dwr  -Dversion=3.0.0-rc2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/Users/davea/.m2/repository//org/directwebremoting/dwr/3.0.0-rc2/dwr-3.0.0-rc2.jar  -Durl=dav:https://repository-myco.forge.cloudbees.com/private  -DrepositoryId=cloudbees-private
```

but am getting this unhelpful error message.  Any ideas what else I should check?  Following the error is my ~.m2/settings.xml file.

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 02:44:56-0600) 
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.0.4 
Java version: 1.6.0_37, vendor: Apple Inc.  
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home 
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman  
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.7.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"   
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on. 
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /opt/apache-maven-3.0.4/conf/settings.xml  
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /Users/davea/.m2/settings.xml    
[DEBUG] Using local repository at /Users/davea/.m2/repository   
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10 for /Users/davea/.m2/repository   
[INFO] Scanning for projects... 
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project org.mainco.subco:myproject:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: (none)    
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging war from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]   
[DEBUG] Resolving plugin prefix deploy from [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]   
[DEBUG] Resolved plugin prefix deploy to org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin from POM org.mainco.subco:myproject:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT  
[DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================ 
[DEBUG] Project: org.mainco.subco:myproject:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT    
[DEBUG] Tasks:   [deploy:deploy-file]   
[DEBUG] Style:   Aggregating    
[DEBUG] ======================================================================= 
[INFO]                                                                          
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Building myproject-war 1.0-SNAPSHOT  
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[DEBUG] Resolving plugin prefix deploy from [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]   
[DEBUG] Resolved plugin prefix deploy to org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin from POM org.mainco.subco:myproject:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT  
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]   
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]   
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]  
[DEBUG] === PROJECT BUILD PLAN ================================================ 
[DEBUG] Project:       org.mainco.subco:myproject:1.0-SNAPSHOT  
[DEBUG] Dependencies (collect): []  
[DEBUG] Dependencies (resolve): []  
[DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [cloudbees-private (https://repository-myco.forge.cloudbees.com/private/, releases+snapshots), maven2-repository.dev.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2/, releases), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases)]  
[DEBUG] Repositories (plugins)     : [repository.jboss.org_thirdparty-releases (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases, releases), repository.jboss.org_thirdparty-uploads (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-uploads, releases), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases)]    
[DEBUG] ----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli)   
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular  
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>   
<configuration> 
  <artifactId>${artifactId}</artifactId>    
  <classifier>${classifier}</classifier>    
  <classifiers>${classifiers}</classifiers> 
  <description>${generatePom.description}</description> 
  <file>${file}</file>  
  <files>${files}</files>   
  <generatePom default-value="true">${generatePom}</generatePom>    
  <groupId>${groupId}</groupId> 
  <javadoc>${javadoc}</javadoc> 
  <localRepository default-value="${localRepository}"/> 
  <offline default-value="${settings.offline}"/>    
  <packaging>${packaging}</packaging>   
  <pomFile>${pomFile}</pomFile> 
  <project default-value="${project}"/> 
  <repositoryId default-value="remote-repository">${repositoryId}</repositoryId>    
  <repositoryLayout default-value="default">${repositoryLayout}</repositoryLayout>  
  <retryFailedDeploymentCount default-value="1">${retryFailedDeploymentCount}</retryFailedDeploymentCount>  
  <sources>${sources}</sources> 
  <types>${types}</types>   
  <uniqueVersion default-value="true">${uniqueVersion}</uniqueVersion>  
  <updateReleaseInfo default-value="false">${updateReleaseInfo}</updateReleaseInfo> 
  <url>${url}</url> 
  <version>${version}</version> 
</configuration>    
[DEBUG] ======================================================================= 
[INFO]  
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) @ myproject ---    
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api   
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api   
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core 
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.transfer < plexus.core  
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core    
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.metadata < plexus.core  
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core  
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.collection < plexus.core    
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.version < plexus.core   
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core  
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core 
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core   
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core   
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core   
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core 
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.repository < plexus.core    
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core   
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core    
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.artifact < plexus.core  
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.spi < plexus.core   
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core    
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core    
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core 
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core 
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core   
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core 
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core    
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core   
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.graph < plexus.core 
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.* < plexus.core 
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core 
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core  
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.impl < plexus.core  
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core  
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core    
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.deployment < plexus.core    
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core  
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core  
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core   
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core    
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core  
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.installation < plexus.core  
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core   
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core  
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core  
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core   
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core 
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core 
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core 
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core    
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core    
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core  
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.resolution < plexus.core    
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core   
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core 
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core   
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api    
[DEBUG] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7:   
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6:compile  
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6:compile 
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6:compile 
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6:compile  
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6:compile 
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6:compile   
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6:compile  
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile 
[DEBUG]          junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:compile  
[DEBUG]          classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2:compile    
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6:compile   
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6:compile    
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.6:compile   
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api    
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7  
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7    
[DEBUG]   Included: junit:junit:jar:3.8.1   
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.6  
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6    
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6   
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6    
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6   
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6    
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6    
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1   
[DEBUG]   Excluded: classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2 
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6  
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6   
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@69cd2e5f]  
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file' with basic configurator --> 
[DEBUG]   (f) artifactId = dwr  
[DEBUG]   (f) file = /Users/davea/.m2/repository/org/directwebremoting/dwr/3.0.0-rc2/dwr-3.0.0-rc2.jar  
[DEBUG]   (f) generatePom = true    
[DEBUG]   (f) groupId = org.directwebremoting   
[DEBUG]   (s) localRepository =        id: local    
      url: file:///Users/davea/.m2/repository/  
   layout: none 

[DEBUG]   (f) offline = false   
[DEBUG]   (f) packaging = jar   
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: org.mainco.subco:myproject:1.0-SNAPSHOT @ /Users/davea/Dropbox/workspace/myproject/pom.xml    
[DEBUG]   (f) repositoryId = cloudbees-private  
[DEBUG]   (f) repositoryLayout = default    
[DEBUG]   (f) retryFailedDeploymentCount = 1    
[DEBUG]   (f) uniqueVersion = true  
[DEBUG]   (f) updateReleaseInfo = false 
[DEBUG]   (f) url = dav:https://repository-myco.forge.cloudbees.com/private 
[DEBUG]   (f) version = 3.0.0-rc2   
[DEBUG] -- end configuration -- 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE    
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Total time: 0.662s   
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jan 08 14:02:33 CST 2013    
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/81M 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project myproject: Cannot deploy artifact from the local repository: /Users/davea/.m2/repository/org/directwebremoting/dwr/3.0.0-rc2/dwr-3.0.0-rc2.jar -> [Help 1] 
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project myproject: Cannot deploy artifact from the local repository: /Users/davea/.m2/repository/org/directwebremoting/dwr/3.0.0-rc2/dwr-3.0.0-rc2.jar 
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)  
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)  
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)  
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)  
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)  
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)  
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)  
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)   
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156) 
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537) 
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)  
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)    
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)    
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)  
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)  
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)    
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)    
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Cannot deploy artifact from the local repository: /Users/davea/.m2/repository/org/directwebremoting/dwr/3.0.0-rc2/dwr-3.0.0-rc2.jar    
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployFileMojo.execute(DeployFileMojo.java:283)   
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)  
    ... 19 more 
[ERROR]     
[ERROR]     
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:   
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

My ~.m2/settings.xml file

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
 <profiles>
   <profile>
     <id>default</id>
     <repositories>
       <repository>
         <id>cloudbees-private</id>
         <name>Cloudbees private repo</name>
         <url>https://repository-myco.forge.cloudbees.com/private/</url>
       </repository>
     </repositories>
   </profile>
 </profiles>
 <activeProfiles>
   <activeProfile>default</activeProfile>
 </activeProfiles>

<servers>
    <server>
      <username>username</username>
      <password>password</password>
      <id>cloudbees-private</id>
    </server>
  </servers>

</settings>
```

Comment: Did you get this artifact through a dependency or via a local build into your local repository? Have you build it yourself ?

Comment: I got this artifact by downloading the JAR file and running the mvn install:install-file command to install it myself.  The artifact is not available in a central Maven repo.

Comment: Just try to copy the artifact into an other directory retry your call.

Comment: I copied to my home dirctory and re-running the command gave me a different error, "No connector available to access repository," but one I might be able to deal with.  Updates to follow

Comment: Running into the same problem. Interesting. I wonder why that is done..

Comment: Hi @Dave. It has been quite a while, but do you mind marking my answer as correct? It's clearly the right one. Thanks.

Answer (score 44):

I don't know why, but deploy-file gives that error when you supply artifact path installed in the local repository. (More precisely when the file parameter is the exact location that artifact would have in the local repository).

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-gpg-plugin/1.5/org/apache/maven/plugin/gpg/SignAndDeployFileMojo.java/#326

Moving the artifact file (normaly the jar) somewhere else and passing this path as the file parameter, solves the problem.

Comment: Just moving the jar somewhere solved my problem, thnx!

Comment: In my case, I just renamed the jar (but left it in the same directory) and it started working...I don't get it.

Answer (score 13):

Starting from version 2.5 the deploy plugin checks if the file to upload resides in the local repository and refuses the upload if that’s the case. You could specify version 2.4 of the plugin as a work-around:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.4:deploy-file \
  -DgroupId=org.directwebremoting \
  -DartifactId=dwr \
  -Dversion=3.0.0-rc2 \
  -Dpackaging=jar \
  -Dfile=/Users/davea/.m2/repository//org/directwebremoting/dwr/3.0.0-rc2/dwr-3.0.0-rc2.jar \
  -Durl=dav:https://repository-myco.forge.cloudbees.com/private \
  -DrepositoryId=cloudbees-private
```

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this whilst trying to migrate a load of dependencies from one private repository to another.

My solution was to simply make a soft link to the repository location (e.g. using `ln -s`) and reference the artifacts through that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I remember trying to deploy a file to my Cloudbees repository and it wouldn't work either.  At the time, I queried Cloudbees about it through their forums, and one of their support folks deployed it in for me.

They do have some doco about it

http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/CloudBees+Private+Maven+Repository

I think it's more about how the CLoudbees server accepts the requests, rather than you doing anything wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to reverse your approach. Download it locally and deploy to the repository manager straight away from the downloaded file and then do NOT install into the local repository, but rather as a first test see if it proxies fine from the repo manager.

That will improve you flow by adding a test as well as provide a work around for the restriction of the deploy plugin and save you the execution of the install-file goal.

I am not certain why that restriction is part of the plugin but I suspect it has something to do with the meta data about the component in the local repository as compared to in a repository manager.

Answer (score -1):

The wagon-webdav connector is needed. Create a temporary POM file to provide that information:

```
<project>
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>dummy</groupId>
   <artifactId>dummy</artifactId>
   <version>1</version>
   <build>
      <extensions>
         <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-webdav</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
         </extension>
      </extensions>
   </build>
</project>
```